# Storing an variant of references for a view type in C++

Tags: c++, reference, variant

I have an environment where I have no C++17 (C++14 ATM) features nor boost.

Currently I have a class responsible for sending messages between services in our domain, this class uses multiple types of addressing (both types are non trivial) and one of them can be converted to other (lets say A can be converted to B).
Class that is responsible for sending messages, contains of multiple (templated, because messages have no base class) methods, duplicated for both of the addressing types using function overload.

```
class Sender{
public:
// old API
template<typename TReq>
send(const A&target, TReq req){send(target, make_request{req});}

// old API
template<typename TReq>
send(const B&target, TReq req){sendB(target, make_request{req});}

protected:
// done for mocking/testing purpose only
virtual send(const A&target, MessageProxy message);
virtual sendB(const A&target, MessageProxy message);
};
```

Addressing A and B is done interchangeable by the users (they don't care if this is A or B type of address) In order to play nice with google mock I need to provide different names for overloaded methods (I could do this in mock, but decided to call them differently here, there is no difference)

The problem that I want to solve is simple. Provide a single virtual send method, that will take an "union" of references to address type A or B (think of it as variant<A&, B&>) that can be used the same way as templated versions of those methods, like.

```
virtual send(const TargetProxy &target, MessageProxy message);
```

that can be used

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, send(Eq(A{}), Message{}))...
EXPECT_CALL(mock, send(Eq(B{}), OtherMessage{}))...
```

The type that carry A& or B& (TargetProxy) should hold an const Reference to A OR to B and should be used only to pass A or B from templated send to virtual send, but I failed to figure out a simple solution for this

Comment: `std::pair<A*,B*>` and make sure always one of them is `nullptr` ?

Comment: If I do send(std::pair<*,*>, ...) I'll loose value semantics, and doing  EXPECT_CALL(mock, send( <<and what should be put here??>> ,_)) would be strange at best

Comment: Define simple. I think you could utilize [type erasure](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjyztj4ntvzAhVohf0HHUYABucQwqsBegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DQGcVXgEVMJg&usg=AOvVaw2ODRZOLiKtUxygTPeic7Yg) here, but the boilerplate needed to be written might be overkill for your needs...

Comment: Basically as simple as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of boilerplate missing, but PoC might be sth like this:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B {};

struct EitherRef : private std::pair<A*, B*>
{
    EitherRef(A& a)
    : std::pair<A*, B*>(std::addressof(a), nullptr){};
    EitherRef(B& b)
    : std::pair<A*, B*>(nullptr, std::addressof(b)){};

    bool hasA() const {return this->first!=nullptr;}
    bool hasB() const {return this->second;}
    operator A&() { assert (this->first);return *this->first; }
    operator B&() { assert (this->second);return *this->second; }

};

template <typename Func>
void applyVisitor(EitherRef e, Func f)
{
    if (e.hasA()) {
        f(static_cast<A&>(e));
    } else if (e.hasB()) {
        f(static_cast<B&>(e));
    }
}

void f(const EitherRef& r)
{
    struct {
        void operator()(A&) {
            std::cout <<"A\n";
        }
        void operator()(B&) {
            std::cout <<"B\n";
        }
    } v;
    applyVisitor(r, v);
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    A a1;
    B b1;
    EitherRef ra{a1};
    EitherRef rb{b1};
    f(ra);
    f(rb);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tested couple of ways based on this idea, and your is shortest but not the most performant :) please take a look https://godbolt.org/z/Y8scE5MoM

Comment: @Bartoszek fine by me. As I wrote, my code is a proof of concept. If you wanted performance - sure, go with the union. BTW, Boost license should probably (but I'm no lawyer) allow you to copy-paste their `variant` into your codebase, so it might be yet another option.

Comment: I didn't said performance is top priority, this was just an observation from godbolt. Your suggested answer was a base idea that I tested in other slightly modified versions.